# Entity Manager : primary and foreign key at the same time

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have a trouble, i can't create an entity,

User(id,username,lastname,...,pwd)

Contact(idUser, idContact)

I would like to create the entity Contact which contains user and contact as primary key and foreign key
in reference to user.id, user and contact are both id's User

Here is my entity Contact :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contact")
public class Contact {
     
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user-fk")
    private User idUser;
     
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="contact-fk")
    private User idContact;
 
    public User getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
 
    public void setIdUser(User idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }
 
    public User getIdContact() {
        return idContact;
    }
 
    public void setIdContact(User idContact) {
        this.idContact = idContact;
    }
```

Here is my entity User :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String userName;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String password;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="emet")
private List<Message> messageEmet;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="recept")
private List<Message> messageRecept;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="idUser")
private List<Contact> idUser;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="idContact")
private List<Contact> idContact;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<Message> getMessageEmet() {
    return messageEmet;
}

public void setMessageEmet(List<Message> messageEmet) {
    this.messageEmet = messageEmet;
}

public List<Message> getMessageRecept() {
    return messageRecept;
}

public void setMessageRecept(List<Message> messageRecept) {
    this.messageRecept = messageRecept;
}

public List<Contact> getIdUser() {
    return idUser;
}

public void setIdUser(List<Contact> idUser) {
    this.idUser = idUser;
}

public List<Contact> getIdContact() {
    return idContact;
}

public void setIdContact(List<Contact> idContact) {
    this.idContact = idContact;
}
```

I really need help, i can't make my page without the table Contact

Comment: where is your @IdClass for the Contact class? Composite PKs need IdClass defining

Comment: How do i do That ? (sorry for my english)

Comment: Read the docs for your JPA implementation perhaps? The one I use is http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html